# C++ Opengl render part of an image

Tags: c++, image, opengl, rendering

Let's say i have a method that get a GLuint texture as a parameter and I'd like to render a part of it. Think about a tile set for instance, i want to be able to load a tile set and render parts (tiles) of it when I load my level.

It would be optimal if I somehow would be able to define the height, width, posX and posY in pixel coordinates from the tile set to draw from.

I've been trying for hours now and any help would be appreciated.

Simplified version of how I currently draw a texture:

```
    void Render::draw(GLuint texture, float posX, float posY, float sizeX, float sizeY) {

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER,0.1f);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(posX,posY,0);
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

    //Bottom-left vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 0);
    glVertex2f( -sizeX,-sizeY);
    //Bottom-right vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 0);
    glVertex2f(sizeX,-sizeY);
    //Top-right vertex (corner) 
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(sizeX,sizeY);
    //Top-left vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 1);
    glVertex2f( -sizeX,sizeY);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this using `glTexCoord` function.
For example, if you tileset contains 4 tiles, and you want to display the top left corner[*] tile, you would do something like this:

```
glTexCoord2f( 0, 0);
glVertex2f( -sizeX,-sizeY);
glTexCoord2f( 0.5, 0);
glVertex2f(sizeX,-sizeY);
glTexCoord2f( 0.5, 0.5);
glVertex2f(sizeX,sizeY);
glTexCoord2i( 0, 0.5);
glVertex2f( -sizeX,sizeY);
```

[*] I don't remember how the coordinates work exactly, but it is easy to test in you code.

Comment: Yeah, but those values go from 0 to 1, do you know any way for me to define the position by using pixel coordinates instead?

Comment: I finally figured it out! For those who are interested I found the solution on: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/559980-opengl-and-2d-tiles/